# Map Json Data to new key-value pair JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapping, key-value

I want to map one json data to a new javascript object like following. Here the json data is dynamic and can have more files with more users. The group information is new and it depends on parent-child information. Can anyone please help me out? Thank you for your time.

Before:

```
{
  "userinfo": {
    "/home/user/main/sub/info/1stfile.txt": {
      "John": "something",
      "Mike": "something",
      "Merry": "something",
      "Susan": "something"
    },
    "/home/user/main/info/2ndfile.txt": {
      "Mulan": "something",
      "James": "something"
    },
    "/home/user/main/info/3rdfile.txt": {
      "Nancy": "something"
    },
    "/home/user/main/4thfile.txt": {
      "Kamal": "something",
      "Xian": "something",
      "Mila": "something"
    }
  }
}
```

After:

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "1stfile",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "John",
          "group": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike",
          "group": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Merry",
          "group": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Susan",
          "group": "1"
        }
      ],
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "2ndfile",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Mulan",
          "group": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "James",
          "group": 2
        }
      ],
      "group": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "3rdfile",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Nancy",
          "group": 3
        }
      ],
      "group": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "4thfile",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Kamal",
          "group": 4
        },
        {
          "name": "Xian",
          "group": 4
        },
        {
          "name": "Mila",
          "group": 4
        }
      ],
      "group": 4
    }
  ],
  "group": 0
}
```

I was trying to build one block of parent-child by using following code

```js
var jsonData = json["userinfo"];
var keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
console.log(keys);
let data = {};
for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
  let g = 1;
  data[j] = { name: keys[j], group: g++ };
}
console.log(data);
```

Which is giving following output

```
{
  0: {
    "name": "/home/user/main/sub/info/1stfile.txt",
    "group": 1
  },
  1: {
    "name": "/home/user/main/info/2ndfile.txt",
    "group": 1
  },
  2: {
    "name": "/home/user/main/info/3rdfile.txt",
    "group": 1
  },
  3: {
    "name": "/home/user/main/4thfile.txt",
    "group": 1
  }
}
```

The value is assigning properly but is creating extra keys (0,1,2,3)!

Comment: Can you show us what have you attempted so far ?

Comment: I have included the code snippet.

Comment: Can you provide a valid before and after ? A valid example of `before` and `after`

Comment: This is a valid example for my task. I've just replaced the user information with "something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need something like this.

You can utilize [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function for your operation.

```html
<script>
  const beforeJSON = `{
    "userinfo": {
      "/home/user/main/sub/info/1stfile.txt": {
        "John": "something",
        "Mike": "something",
        "Merry": "something",
        "Susan": "something"
      },
      "/home/user/main/info/2ndfile.txt": {
        "Mulan": "something",
        "James": "something"
      },
      "/home/user/main/info/3rdfile.txt": {
        "Nancy": "something"
      },
      "/home/user/main/4thfile.txt": {
        "Kamal": "something",
        "Xian": "something",
        "Mila": "something"
      }
    }
  }`
  const before = JSON.parse(beforeJSON);
  const filenames = Object.keys(before.userinfo);

  const after = {
    name: 'main',
    children: [],
    group: 0,
  }

  const children = filenames.map((filename, idx) => {
    const innerChildren = Object.keys(before.userinfo[filename]).map((n) => ({
      name: n,
      group: idx + 1,
    }))
    return ({
      name: filename,
      children: innerChildren,
      group: idx + 1,
    });
  })

  after.children = children;

  console.log(after);
</script>
```

Please format your code next time before posting another question.

Comment: Thank you so much and I'll properly format my questions in future.